# Multiplying number by ten in verilog

Tags: verilog, hdl

How do you multiply a binary number by ten in verilog?
Is it as simple as

```
reg [7:0] a,b;
reg[31:0] p;
b= 8'b00001001;
p=a*b;
```

Upgraded to windows 8 and my xilinx is working atm. Need to know asap for planning stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly - 10 in binary is `1010`! For multiplying two 8-bit numbers, you'll only need 16 bits for the result, so `reg [15:0] p` would do. What about:

```
 always @( a )
     p = a * 8'd10;
```

or

```
wire [13:0] p;
assign p = a * 4'd10;
```

Comment: Are you sure a*b gave 16 bit result? I thought in verilog arithmetic result capasity is the same as its arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how good the HDL synthesis tools are at converting multiplies to bit shifts. I wouldn't want to synthesise a multiplier for this code by accident (even your CPU is unlikely to use a multiply for this).

```
wire [7:0] a;
wire [11:0] shift2;
wire [11:0] shift1;
wire [11:0] result;

assign shift2 = a << 3; // a * 8
assign shift1 = a << 1; // a * 2
assign result = shift2 + shift1;
```

Comment: Modern synthesis tools tend to be very efficient when an operand is fixed. Using a `* constant` also allows power optimizations to be made by the tools, and when pushed for timing they are free to choose faster architectures.